# How to trigger AWS State machine when a website is updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, state-machine, aws-step-functions

https://www.jnto.go.jp/jpn/statistics/since2003_visitor_arrivals.xlsx

I have the above public website. The website or file is updated once a month by the admin of that website. Can you please tell me how to trigger State machine when that above website is updated?

I have looked at API Gateway but it only assign State machine an endpoint to trigger and not triggering the state machine from an endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Because the website is outside your AWS environment, you must periodically poll its information to check if the file was updated.

There's no out-of-the-box solution in AWS. One way to achieve it:

- EventBridge Scheduler: Trigger a lambda every week (eg. Friday)
- DynamoDB Table: To track the "Last-Modified" value
- Lambda: Fetch the URL and check the "Last-Modified" header. Compare it with the value in DynamoDB, it if is different, update DynamoDB and trigger the Step Functions workflow via AWS SDK

References:

- [Creating an Amazon EventBridge rule that runs on a schedule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html)

---

#### Updates 2023-03-15

I shared a demo-ish code using CDK on:

- https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/cdk-eventbridge-scheduler-last-modified

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Eventbridge](https://Eventbridge) to trigger your AWS step function. Create a rule eg. If the last logged in date is changed then an event is triggered which in turn triggers the state function.

[More methods can be found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-invoke-sfn.html)

Comment: Thank you @Min Yoongin. Can you tell me which pattern should I choose for Event bridge rule?